# Proofs that there is no $f(z)$ such that $\exp f(z) = z$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, big-list, exponential-function

When I first learned about this result I was completely stunned that there is no holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\exp f(z) = z$. What are some interesting proofs of this? Here are two I know of.

> > **Proof 1:** Assume we have such an $f(z)$. Then restricted to $\Bbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ we must have $f(z) = \operatorname{Log} z + 2\pi k i$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$. The big log stands for principal log. But now the  $\lim_{z \to a} f(z)$ for any $a \in (-\infty,0]$ does not exist (approaching from the top, the argument approaches $\pi$ but from the bottom it approaches $-\pi$).
> >
> > **Proof 2:** If we had a holomorphic function $f(z)$ such that $\exp f(z) = z$ then differentiating gives $f'(z) = 1/z$ for all $z \neq 0$. Integrating on $|z|=1$, the left gives $0$ by Cauchy's Theorem but the right is $2\pi i$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: The log is defined as the integral of $\frac {dz}{z}$. This integral is well-defined, i.e., independent of path, in a simply-connected region. So $log(f(z)):=g(z): e^{g(z)}=f(z)$ exists precisely in simply-connected regions not containing $0$
In general, an analytic function has an analytic antiderivative only in simply-connected regions.

Comment: So, the argument comes down to the fact that $logf(z):=g(z)$ with $e^{g(z)}=f(z)$, which is equal to $\int d(f(z))/z$ is well-defined, e.g., independent of path, if the region where it is defined is simply-connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that all proofs of this will be morally equivalent. But here is an interesting way to phrase it. Consider the *exponential sheaf sequence* on $X=\mathbf C-\{0\}$ (viewed as a complex manifold):

$$0 \to \mathbf Z \to \mathcal O \xrightarrow{\text{exp}(2\pi i\cdot)} \mathcal O^\times \to 1.$$

The long exact sequence of cohomology begins with

$$0 \to \mathbf Z \to \mathcal O(X) \xrightarrow{\text{exp}(2\pi i\cdot)} \mathcal O^\times(X) \to H^1(X, \mathbf Z) \to \dots.$$

The connecting map $\mathcal O^\times(X) \to H^1(X, \mathbf Z) = \mathbf Z$ is given by $f \mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C df/f$, where $C$ is the unit circle oriented counter-clockwise. (By the residue theorem, this really is an integer.) Now, since $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C dz/z = 1$, the function $z$ cannot be in the image of $\mathcal O(X) \xrightarrow{\text{exp}(2\pi i\cdot)} \mathcal O^\times(X)$.

Comment: I am glad you answered this. Your example above shows that the functor $H^0(X,-)$ is not right-exact :D

Comment: @fppf Precisely! :)

Comment: @fppf Well, I am viewing $X$ as a complex manifold, but yes, the same is true because $X$ is connected. Unfortunately, the exponential sheaf sequence does not exist on a scheme, because the exponential makes no sense. One has to use the Kummer sequence instead (but then we need étale cohomology). :)

Comment: :-o :-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o

Comment: Dear @Sade, would you like to purchase a vowel? :)

Comment: Dearsir,how much?what the most  you ever lost on a coin toss?m surprised coz in math there iss also scheme,what is  dat